# Angularjs ES6 adding filter as class

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to es6 and trying to add a filter to an app but keep getting a module not found error.  Here's what I have:

```
index.module.js

...other app imports
import { GlCapitialize } from './filters/glcapitialize';
...
angular.module...(other app controllers, directives, etc)...
.filter('glCapitialize', GlCapitialize);
```

filter - which is probably completely wrong

```
export function GlCapitialize(input) {
    'ngInject';
    return (input, scope)=> { 
      if (input!=null)
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        return input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+input.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: And which module is not found?

Comment: the filter... export function GlCapitialize()